# JS/Sinon - beforeEach(function(done) not called

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, mocha.js, sinon

Just starting with Sinon, Mocha, and Chai JS. After upgrading UnderscoreJS version from 1.4.4 to 1.9.1, I had to update how my project was using template function.

Previously, _.template function was used in this way -

```
var myTemplate = _.template("<p><%= name %></p>", {name: 'Joe Doe'});
```

New Way,

```
// `myTemplate` here is a function!
var myTemplate = _.template("<p><%= name %></p>");

// Now let's pass in the data for the template.
myTemplate({name: 'Joe Doe'}); // it returns: "<p>Joe Doe</p>"
```

However, this change caused a lot of the existing test cases to fail. Below mentioned is one of the test cases I need help with -

```
    const sinonVar = require('sinon');

    describe('testVar', function() {

    var sanboxVar;
    var ss = requirejs('Path to JS library');
    var testVar;

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        console.log("Not Called");  // Never printed on console
        done();
        sanboxVar = sinonVar.sanbox.create();
    });

    it('some text here', function() {
        console.log("sanboxVar: " + sanboxVar); //Printed on console as 'undefined'
        ss.id = sanboxVar.stub();
    });
});
```

On "npm test", I see the error -

```
testVar
   some text here:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'stub' of undefined
  at Context.<anonymous> (testPage.js) - "This is pointing to sanboxVar not defined"
```

I think for some reason, beforeEach method is not getting called and hence the Sandoval variable is not getting initiated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you debug the test to confirm that the beforeEach method is indeed not getting called

Comment: @Halcyon - Made a few changes in the post for clarity. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: seems that there is an error in previous beforeEach, so that is not reached

Comment: @KaterinaPavlenko - Can you please elaborate what exactly you mean by 'previous beforeEach'?

Comment: uhm, is there a reason for calling done()? as far as I see in the documentation, creating a sandbox is not async (correct me if I am wrong). Also you are calling done() before assigning the value to your variable. I would just use a simple ()=>{} as callback in the beforeEach hook.